# Inducing Paths Definition Ambiguity

Tags: causality, causal-diagram

I am relatively new to the causal discovery space and I have a clarifying question regarding the definition of an inducing path. In Causation, Prediction and Search (page 173), the authors state that a path $U$ is an inducing path "if and only if every member of $O$ on $U$ except for the endpoints is a collider on $U$, and every collider on $U$ is an ancestor of either $A$ or $B$."

One example they give is "$U = \langle A,B,C,D,E,F \rangle$ is an inducing path over $O = \{A,B,D,F\}$". Here is a screenshot of the figure illustrating this: [image]

I understand that $B$ and $D$ must be ancestors of either $A$ or $F$ in order for the second part of the definition to work, but what confuses me is, in this specific example, $F$ has three edges into it (two if you only consider nodes in $O$), meaning $F$ is a collider by definition. This appears to be explicitly prohibited by the first part of the definition. Can anyone help shed light on this idea for me please?

Also, I am new to posting on forums like this. I do not believe this is a repeat question but please let me know if this has been answered elsewhere that google did not prioritize in my search. Thank you!